# Performance of dependency injection and object cloning when working with large objects

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I am developing a lightweight php framework (similar to Slim, but way simpler).
That includes a simplified version of the PSR-7 Stream.

My main question:
In the response body, before it passes through all middleware layers, should I include the actual response body (e.g. image binary data) or just a reference to the file (image path)?

I am particularly concerned with performance when the response object is a large dataset and is:

1. injected multiple times (when passing through various middleware)
2. cloned (when PSR-7 response needs to be modified)

I thought of passing only a reference to the file through the middleware, and generate the data immediately before it is sent to the client, but there will be cases where middleware needs to inspect the body (E.g. verifiy if  CSRF token is include in POST form).

Am I overconcerned with performance in my case?

I have considered exceptions such as controller to decide if response body should be the actual output or just a reference to the file, depending on certina criteria such as content type (e.g. if html send content to the middleware stack). However, this creates unecessary complexity and defeats the purpose of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: It might be worth checking out what other libraries such as Guzzle do: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/cd634c213de11e0f229651173428f5c27d398628/docs/psr7.rst#body: "_The body used in request and response objects is a Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface. This stream is used for both uploading data and downloading data. Guzzle will, by default, store the body of a message in a stream that uses PHP temp streams. When the size of the body exceeds 2 MB, the stream will automatically switch to storing data on disk rather than in memory (protecting your application from memory exhaustion)._"

Comment: "Am I overconcerned with performance in my case" - At the building stage, probably yes. Performance can almost always be improved, but I find getting something working first more important.